# Different webpage results when using Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I was training to scrape on an supermarket website using scrapy :
https://www.pnp.co.za/pnpstorefront/pnp/en/All-Products/Fresh-Food/Milk-%26-Cream/c/milk-and-cream703655157

I noticed that when using chrome, I will get a page showing 106 results over 5 pages. However, when using a spide with scrapy (and other scraping software), the number of results is reduced to 30 products over 2 pages. It seems like the site is limiting the results shown when using scrapy. How would one go around this and have a scrapy spider be seen as my laptop on chrome?

I use the following cmd to run the sypder:

```
scrapy crawl tstPnPCategories -o out.csv
```

And here is the spyder script:

```
import scrapy

class testSpydi(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tstPnPCategories'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.pnp.co.za/pnpstorefront/pnp/en/All-Products/Fresh-Food/Milk-%26-Cream/c/milk-and-cream703655157'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        names = response.css(".item-name::text").extract()

        print("*** *******")
        print("")
       print("NAMES")
        print("")
        print("************")
        for name in names:

            print("")
            print(name)
            print("")
            yield {
                'item': name
            }

        next_page = response.css("li.pagination-next a::attr(href)").get()

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Comment: @jsotola, noted, Tx. Any suggestion on how I could select the region using scrapy ? Have no clue.

Comment: Where you able to solve the issue? Am facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to select a different region to be able to scrape data about more items.

The script has to issue a click on one of the dropdown menu items.

The first item in the dropdown can be clicked by issuing the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-base-store')[0].click()
```

The element was identified by using Developer Tools in Chrome browser.

DevTools is activated by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shft</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or by choosing Developer Tools in the browser menu (three vertical dots)

Here is what to look for.

[image]

Comment: Can find a tool to do clicks with Scrapy

Comment: you should be thinking `how to do webpage clicks with python?`

Comment: Clicking with python is not the issue. The issue is doing it within Scrapy. When using Scrapy I work within the "sparse" function. By that time, the information has already been collected as an html collected in the object "response" that I then search. I can't do clicking within the body of the "parse" function. The clicking actions have to be done before Scrapy fetches the html in order to fetch the right html page / content ... I've been checking how to do that but no luck so far.